# ActiveReports always prints last page when NewPage is set to "After"

Tags: .net, winforms, activereports

I have an ActiveReports file with the **NewPage** property set to **"After"** in the **Detail Section** of my report.  Every time I print, I get an extra page at the end of the report.  How can I prevent this from happening?

The only extra page is the last page.  So I'm pretty sure this is not an issue about page margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making heights = 0 on all subsequent sections, including the Report Footer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to explicitly set the heights of the subsequent sections to zero, you can just set the sections' "CanShrink" properties to "True". That will automatically shrink the sections to the bottom edge of any content inside them.